# How does Magento 2 import a product feed into Pinterest?

Tags: magento2

In Magento2, I want import product feed to Pinterest, But I do not know how to do this.
Please help me in this. 
Thank you very much！

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't have a native option for pinterest product feeds, you will need to create a product feed file that maps a product's attributes to the expected fields and formats that pinterest requires.

You could do this by creating your own custom module or by installing an extension. Amasty has an extension (not free) that let's you do custom field mapping to generate the file on a schedule that makes the most sense for your store. https://amasty.com/product-feed-for-magento-2.html

As mentioned, you'll need to create that feed file specific to the requirements of pinterest. They have a guide for product feeds that provides instructions and field requirements. https://help.pinterest.com/en/business/article/before-you-get-started-with-catalogs

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 does not have out of the box option for importing product feed to Pinterest. You will need to create a product feed file that maps your product attributes to the expected fields and formats that Pinterest requires. You could do this by creating your own custom module or by installing an extension [Product Feed](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-product-feed-manager.html). This extension allows you to create product feeds for various platforms, including Pinterest, Amazon, Google, DooFinder etc. and you can schedule them to run automatically. You can also create feeds in different format TAB, CSV, XML and TXT

Alternatively, you can follow the instructions from Pinterest's guide for product feeds https://help.pinterest.com/en/business/article/before-you-get-started-with-catalogs to create your own product feed file. You will need to include the required fields, such as id, title, link, image_link, price, and availability, as well as some optional fields, such as description, condition, and product_type https://help.pinterest.com/en/business/article/before-you-get-started-with-catalogs.

Once you have created your product feed file, you can upload it to Pinterest using the Catalogs feature. You will need to have a business account and claim your website on Pinterest to use this feature https://help.pinterest.com/en/business/article/before-you-get-started-with-catalogs. You can find more details on how to upload your product feed file and manage your catalog on [Pinterest's help page].

I hope this information helps you import your product feed to Pinterest in Magento 2.